# I am trying to write a numerify code like in Javafakers API

Tags: java

So, I need to replace '#' in a string with a random number(0-9).

Eg: String: "I am l#earning abou#t Jav#a".

I am expecting an output like "I am l1earning abou5t Jav3a".

From the below code, I am getting an output like
"I am l2earning abou2t Jav2a" where the code is generating random numbers but after reruns.

What changes have to be performed in the code to generate different random numbers in the same string?

**Java**

```
import java.util.Random;
public class numerify {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = " I am l#earning abo#ut Jav#a.";
        String num="1234567890";
        Random r= new Random();
        int n=num.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {

            char ran= num.charAt(r.nextInt(n));
            if (str.charAt(i) == '#') {
                str = str.replace('#',ran);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: The javadoc is a really helpful tool, take a look at the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) class, specifically you could make use of `replaceFirst('#',ran)` which "**Replaces the first** substring of this string that matches the given" rather than `replace('#',ran)` which "Returns a string resulting from **replacing all occurrences** of oldChar in this string with newChar."

Answer (score 3):

The method `replace` replaces all occurances.

Try using replaceFirst https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

```
str = str.replaceFirst('#',ran);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is only true for the first time and after that replace will replace all occurrences of `#`, so there is no `#` available to replace next time.

You need to `replace` only one # at a time. Use `replaceFirst` instead.

```
if (str.charAt(i) == '#') {
     char ran= num.charAt(index);
     str = str.replaceFirst("#",Character.toString(ran));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ReplaceFirst() needs to be used instead of Replace().
ReplaceFirst()method replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).